# Strange IO values from sys.dm_io_virtual_filestats

Tags: sql, io

Values for io_stall_read_ms seems to be higher than actual run time for query. The setup:

```
create database filestats;

use filestats;

create table t1_primary(
 a  int     identity
,b  int
,c  datetime
,d  char(780)
,constraint pk_p_a primary key clustered (a));

set nocount on;
declare @n int = 0;

while @n < 12800
begin
    insert into t1_primary select @n, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
select @n += 1
end

set statistics io, time on;

declare @before datetime 

dbcc dropcleanbuffers
checkpoint

if object_id('tempdb..#vfsBefore') is not null
    drop table #vfsBefore

if object_id('tempdb..#vfsAfter') is not null
    drop table #vfsAfter

select * 
into #vfsBefore
from sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(db_id('filestats'), null)

select @before = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

select * from dbo.t1_primary 

select DATEDIFF(ms, @before, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

select * 
into #vfsAfter
from sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(db_id('filestats'), null)

select 
 db_name(b.database_id)
,mf.name
,a.num_of_reads-b.num_of_reads              as NumReads
,a.num_of_bytes_read-b.num_of_bytes_read    as NumBytesRead
,a.io_stall_read_ms-b.io_stall_read_ms      as IOStallReadMS
,a.num_of_writes-b.num_of_writes            as NumWrites
,a.num_of_bytes_written-b.num_of_bytes_written  as NumBytesWritten
,a.io_stall_write_ms-b.io_stall_write_ms    as IOStallWriteMS
,a.io_stall-b.io_stall                      as IOStallTotal
,a.size_on_disk_bytes-b.size_on_disk_bytes  as SizeOnDiskBytes
,mf.physical_name
from #vfsBefore b
join #vfsAfter a on b.database_id = a.database_id and b.file_id =     a.file_id
join sys.master_files mf on b.database_id = mf.database_id and b.file_id = mf.file_id
```

Running this results in the following:

**Virtual file stats:** num_of_reads = 26, io_stall_read_ms = 2153

**Statistics IO:** Table 't1_primary'. Scan count 1, logical reads 2571, physical reads 3, read-ahead reads 2552

**Statistics time:** CPU time = 46 ms, elapsed time = 595 ms.

**Run time, DATEDIFF function:** 593 ms

Not surprisingly a clustered index scan is performed, single threaded. How come the io_stall_read_ms value is higher than the time executing the query. What is going on here?

Could it be that it is, 2153 (io_stall_ms)/26 (num_reads) = ~83ms io stalls per read op?

Sincerely,

Gord

Comment: This might be better placed on `dba.stackexchange`. [This answer here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46007/5489) might help - as you've suggested, it seems that the cumulative stall time differential needs to be divided out by #operations to make sense.

Comment: Yep, that sounds indeed reasonable! The answer you're linking to seems like the right answer, thank you very much! Posted the same question on dba.stackexchange.com with an unregistered user (user62622), and got into some trouble when trying to reply to other user comments because my reputation wasn't high enough yet...